# Symfony CheckboxType could not be unchecked

Tags: checkbox, symfony, symfony-forms

Here are the existing codes:

Form type as :

```
->add('isProcessor', CheckboxType::class,array('label' => 'As Processor', 'required'=>false))
```

Entity as:

```
/**
 * @var boolean $isProcessor
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_processor", type="boolean")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $isProcessor;
```

page as :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbAli.png)

How could I make this happen:

- if the checkbox is checked, isProcessor should be true
- if the checkbox is unchecked, isProcessor should be false

I am not if there should be some other parameters with CheckboxType when building the form. Or I need add some other codes to convert the values.

Also the field could not be modified in modify page.
Is there any way to make the checkbox element disable in modify page but enable in create page?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you just have to remove NotBlank constraint on $isProcessor. If checkbox isn't checked, then the form value will be null and the boolean type convert it to 0.

To make the checkbox element disable in modify page but not in create page, you can use createForm options.

In your controller :

```
$form = $this->createForm(YourType::class, $yourData, [
            'isProcessorDisable'    => true // or false
        ]);
```

In your form type, you can do something like that :

```
class YourType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $isProcessorDisable = $options['isProcessorDisable'];
        $builder->add('isProcessor', CheckboxType::class, array(
            'label'    => 'As Processor', 
            'required' => false,
            'disabled' => $isProcessorDisable
        ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class'                => YourEntity::class,
            'translation_domain'        => 'form',
            'isProcessorDisable'        => false // Default value
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for your help. It works fine. Many many thanks again.